# Public geth proxy

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan

Is there any public geth proxy like [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/apis#proxy) provides?

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://infura.io/ to create your own dedicated proxy for the network.

Answer (score 0):

Guess is just a node client, I guess you are looking for something like https://etherscan.io/apis ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for a service that supports geth-like api, so my requests can be translated to the daemon returning me it's answer. I'm trying to create a some sort of lightweight client, so I need at least to have ability of getting nonce, balance, gasPrice, call estimateGas, sendRawTransaction, balance/decimals contract functions and so on.
Etherscan provides proxy for such things, but I'd like to find out some other to have reserve in case of ES being unavailable.

Comment: Then you need to use infura.io, as mentioned below. But beware, some functionalities like filtering are not supported, also transaction broadcasting can be catastrophically slow and unreliable at times.